# Website recognizing android phone

Tags: android

So I'm developing an app with a friend. In a nutshell, the app should navigate to a server and display a JPG to the user.  If one navigates to that web page from a regular computer, the user views a PDF of the same information. Essentially, the server should recognize whether or not the user is on an Android phone and send the user either a PDF or a JPG of the PDF. What sort of code should I use in the app to accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: Is the android app navigating to the website with WebView?

Comment: What server do you use? apache, .. ?

Comment: It would help others incl. myself to respond to your post if you give more details ...how does the app "navigate" to the server and display the JPEG if you are not using a WebView?

Comment: Yes, the server is a vps apache server.

Comment: I haven't written any code yet, I was just wondering if this was possible. Sorry I should have been more clear!

Comment: @Slicekick You shouldn't write anything in your app. It's already taken care of for you. Android's default browser already identifies itself as such via the user agent string. If you're not navigating through the browser, then you need to use `HttpGet#setHeader()` as @Whiler suggested below.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [post](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/redirect-mobile-devices-using-htaccess) on how to redirect devices within the htaccess file. Basically it parses the user agent for android, iphone, etc. If it's some sort of custom browser you app is using, just append some code in the user agent that will tell the server it's a phone/device.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the useragent sent by the browser. It differs from phone and PC.

For exemple, browse [this page](http://whatsmyuseragent.com/) with the mobile and with your PC. You'll see the difference.

If you are directly downloading it, you can set yourself your useragent, ie:

```
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
    request.setHeader("User-Agent", "MyUserAgentFromMyPhone");

    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

Comment: I'm not navigating through the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Without question. [Device Atlas](http://deviceatlas.com/) is the way to go

They have the UserAgent for almost every device in existence and there should be a way to get it functioning on any platform.

I use C# and they have a nice interface for us to determine not only what type of device it is but also what the screen size is and what capabilities the device has.

Hands down The best device detection system I have ever seen.

Answer (score 0):

you can check the operating system in javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(navigator.platform == 'android')
 //redirect the user to the page of android
 window.location.href='......'

</script>
```